# How to get Project Path in a Java Spring Web App

Tags: java, web

This is my project structure:

[Spring web App Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiNJi.png)

as you can see I have the images folder where I need to transfer the product pictures. But the next lines of codes:

```
MultipartFile productImage = newProduct.getProductImage();
    String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    if(productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            productImage.transferTo(new File(rootDirectory + "resources\\images\\" + newProduct.getProductId() + ".png"));

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Product Image Saving failed", ex);
        }
    }
```

After to add a new product the product image is uploaded to:
C:\Users\PC\sts_ws\spring-java-app\module2\1\webstore\target\webstore-1.0-SNAPSHOT\resources\images

But I need the path:
C:\Users\PC\sts_ws\spring-java-app\module2\1\webstore\src\main\webapp\resources\images

I dont know how to point to my desired path.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Try it: 
Paths.get(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("xyz/file.extension").toURI())

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
ClassLoader resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
URL path = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/THEPATH ".png");
```

And if you want to get that you can use this,

```
File file = new File(path.getFile());
```